# DEOptim lower and upper values

Tags: r, optimization

I'm optimizing coefficients using two methods: general optimization using DEOptim and local optimization using the Optim function. Here is the minimization function:

```
function(data, par){
  sum(
    (data$CCI - 
       (par[1]+par[2]*log10(data$Landsat) +
          par[3]*log10(data$Landsat)^2 +
          par[4]*log10(data$Landsat)^3 + 
          par[5]*log10(data$Landsat^4)))^2, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

And here's how I'm using the DEOptim function :

```
global_optimization_buffer <- DEoptim(min.RSS, lower, upper, data = DATA_buffer, DEoptim.control(itermax = 10000))
```

I'm a little surprised since I got better results using the local optimization method. Here's the results I got with the local optimizaition :
[local_opti][1]

And here's the results I got using the global optimization :
[global_opti][2]

I also noticed that I get way better results when putting my lower and lower values to a smaller range (previous image with coefficients range btw -10 & 10 and here's the results with coefficients range btw -5 & 5).
[global_smaller_range_opti][3]

Knowing that increasing the number of iteration does not change anything my question is : Is there a better way of using the DEOptim library ? Am I using this function correctly ?
My dataset contain 3500 x 2 values. The first 3500 values are used as "true values" and have a range between -1 & 2.5 and have a mean value of -0.07. The second part of the dataset is used in a function called OC3 :

```
function(coeff, landsat_values) {
  log_chloa <- coeff[1] + coeff[2]*log10(landsat_values) +
    coeff[3]*log10(landsat_values)^2 +
    coeff[4]*log10(landsat_values)^3 +
    coeff[5]*log10(landsat_values)^4
  return(log_chloa)
}
```

This part of my dataset have value between 0.27 and 107 with a mean value of 1.65
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JGhv.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi3mi.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5N6K.png

Comment: You might get more helpful answers if you posted a reproducible example (i.e. with data). But you add several powers of a regressor, which makes it likely that your data matrix is badly conditioned. In such cases, Differential Evolution often works better with a larger population size.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Expanding my comment: You only describe your data, but do not show them.
Here is a made-up example.  I use a different implementation of Differential Evolution (DE), `DEopt` from package [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF) (which I maintain).

I create a random `X` matrix (which corresponds to your `landsat_values`).

```
n <- 3500
x <- rnorm(n)
X <- cbind(1, x, x*x, x*x*x, x*x*x*x)
```

I precompute the powers of `x`, as they are fixed throughout the optimization.
Now I create 'true' parameters `true.p` and see if `DEopt` and `optim` can recover them.  The `y` correspond to your `CCI` data.

```
true.p <- rnorm(ncol(X))
## y <- rnorm(n, sd = 5)  ## random y
y <- X %*% true.p
```

Your objective function, rewritten in matrix form (since `X` now holds the precomputed powers):

```
mse <- function(p, y, X) {
    res <- y - (X %*% p)
    sum(res*res)/nrow(X)
}
```

Run DE:

```
library("NMOF")
sol <- DEopt(OF = mse,
             algo = list(nG = 200,
                         nP = 50,
                         min = rep(-10, ncol(X)),
                         max = rep( 10, ncol(X)),
                         minmaxConstr = TRUE),
             X = X,
             y = y)
sol$OFvalue
## [1] 1.542069e-13
```

Which is essentially zero.

We recovered the true parameters:

```
## returned parameter values
sol$xbest
##[1] -1.1973190  1.0711195  1.6913071 -0.8870736 -1.1728667
true.p
## [1] -1.1973190  1.0711191  1.6913067 -0.8870735 -1.1728667
```

And now with `optim` (unconstrained, in this case):

```
optim(rep(1, ncol(X)), fn = mse, X = X, y = y,
      control = list(maxit = 10000, reltol = 1e-12))
## $par
## [1] -1.1973165  1.0711397  1.6913174 -0.8870751 -1.1728689
## 
## $value
## [1] 4.222055e-10
## 
## $counts
## function gradient 
##     1574       NA 
## 
## $convergence
## [1] 0
## 
## $message
## NULL
##
```

And we recovered the parameters as well. So, for my data, both functions seem to be able to handle the model.